# A simple hit counter

Tags: php

I've got a simple hit counter for my site, which looks like this:

```
if(file_exists($statfile))
    $count=file_get_contents($statfile)+1;
file_put_contents($statfile, $count, LOCK_EX);
```

The statfile is a simple text file containing nothing else for that subpage's hit count. When receiving a hit for it, we read the file's contents, increase the number, and write it back.

That's okay, except that, at random times, I'm experiencing restarting the counting. I don't know why. I hoped LOCK_EX would solve it, but it didn't; it restarted.

My earlier solution was keeping all counters in the same file as a serialized array, but the file was corrupted frequently. However, it wasn't even big, only 55 numbers for now.

What am I doing wrong?

I have no idea what to try. The counter was above 20K on either day, but I saw a few hundred the following day. NB. The database is not an option.

Comment: "*What am I doing wrong?*" At any semblance of significant request volume, your fundamental design is particularly suboptimal. It's probable your code is encountering something of a race condition where the file is locked by another PHP invocation and a subsequent execution's call to `file_get_contents()` returns `false` as a result, which coalesces to `0`. That script would then overwrite the file with a "reset" value count. The solution is to use a proper architecture, i.e. a database, a message queue, an external analytics service... etc.

Comment: If `get_file_contents` ever came back empty, that would "reset" the number in the file.

Comment: "*Database is not an option.*" Can you elaborate as to *why*? This is highly likely the answer that best balances cost and complexity to implement, and without sufficient context seems an arbitrary requirement (at best). Could you use a message queue with a producer/consumer architecture to batch requests at specific intervals & prevent this reliance on a filesystem for this type of thing?

Comment: Why even bother? You're introducing security issues for something that could be done by just grepping the existing web server logs.

Comment: "Database is not an option." not even a SQLite instance?

Comment: Yes, database is over the limit since it’s a paid option with my provider and I don’t want to pay.

Comment: Well, both esqew and Scott Hunter are saying file_get_contents may return a zero. Now, this almost solves the problem. Thank you. If a zero is returned, I mustn’t write it out, OK. Now, database being out of option, and I wouldn’t want to apply an external analytics service (I’m tired to learn things all the time, and this is a small task), what is a message queue, please? How to apply it in this case?

Comment: You don't need an external analytics service. Just grep the logfile you already have and count the matches: `grep -c <page_url> <path_to_log>` and you're done. Building a message queue just to count page hits is wildly unnecessary overkill.